# Kotlin does not understand ViewModelProviders.of(activity ?: fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

Inside my `Fragment` I initialize a `ViewModel` using `ViewModelProviders`.
I want it to take its `Activity` if not `null`, otherwise itself (`Fragment`).

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(activity ?: this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
}
```

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
>
> - of(Fragment) defined in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
> - of(FragmentActivity) defined in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelPro

It seems the language does not allow me to invoke conflicting method signatures (between `of(Activity)` and `of(Fragment)`. (It might be understandable, maybe the compiler has to reference only one method and cannot link to both on the same line.) **Is that so?**

I now have to use

```
    activity?.let {
        ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    } ?: run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

**Is there any better way of doing this?**

Comment: Yes, java doesn't allow this either because the method overload is chosen [at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), Kotlin's bytecode is bound by the same restriction, although they could generate your workaround code under the hood. It would only work if there was a method that would take a common supertype of `Activity` and `Fragment`, e.g. `Context`. If you do that frequently, add one? A bit shorter: `activity.let { it?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it) } ?: ViewModelProviders.of(this) }.get(ViewModel::class.java)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's **compiler ambiguity**, because you're passing `activity` & `this (fragment instance)` at the same time which has different implementations in **`ViewModelProviders`**.

**Another approach** to do this is by using **`when`** condition like below, *(although your approach is also good)*:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by lazy {
    return@lazy when {
        activity != null -> {
            ViewModelProviders.of(activity as FragmentActivity).get(MainViewModel::class.java) // you can either pass activity object
        }
        else -> {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java) // or pass fragment object, both are not possible at same time.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using androidx so should add two lines for lifecycle :

```
 def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

and use it like this :

```
 val mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: This is good answer. Slight change just add this (implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0')

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jeel's answer, I'd recommend that if you commonly need to use this pattern, you should define an extension function on `Fragment` for it to avoid repetition. For example:

```
fun Fragment.getViewModelProvider() =
    activity?.let(ViewModelProviders::of) ?: ViewModelProviders.of(this)

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel() = 
    getViewModelProvider().get(T::class.java)
```

From there, within any `Fragment` you can just call either:

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel = getViewModel()
val viewModel = getViewModel<MainViewModel>()
```

It'll avoid both the boilerplate of fetching the provider as well as specifying the Java class specifically.

Comment: I already made an extension like the first one you wrote. But thanks for posting this as I'm sure it would help others. Upvoted.