# How access the ViewModel inside an Activity using ViewModelProviders.of()?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

First of all this is not a duplicate question, I have tried all the other methods found here on **SO** but they didn't solve my problem.
I'm having a problem with the ViewModelProviders. These are my codes.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(VideoPlayerViewModel::class.java)
```

The 'this' is giving an error. Here's the error

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
of(Fragment) defined in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
of(FragmentActivity) defined in androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
```

This is my class

```
class VideoPlayerActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: VideoPlayerViewModel
}
```

As I said I have read some other answers regarding to this problem and they are telling me to extend **AppCompatActivity()** instead of **Activity()**.
The problem is when i change to **AppCompatActivity()** it does solve the error but gives a whole lot of error in my other codes. So i want to do it without changing the **Activity()**.
What is the solution?

Comment: see that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52811933/4854891

Comment: `Activity` is raw system implementation you shouldn't extend directly (in most cases anyway). `AppCompatActivity` is androidx library extension of `Activity` which you should use as it implements most functionality or hooks for androidx to work properly like `ViewModelProvider` in your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin does not understand ViewModelProviders.of(activity ?: fragment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811685/kotlin-does-not-understand-viewmodelproviders-ofactivity-fragment)